# Is there way in Intellij to quickly preview only user live templates?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have bunch of Live Templates I created. Sometimes I don't recall the abbreviation I used, I want to quickly preview all "user defined" live templates. 
Is there a way to do it?
Similar to what's shown below but without typing first couple of characters.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Right now you can go to settings and look at them. http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-84705 can make them more distinguishable. If you have any other ideas, you could submit them to the tracker yourself.

Comment: What I am looking for is ability to list all the available Live Templates with associated keyword trigger right from the editor, without going to the settings.